# How to build installshield project using devenv bypassing MSbuild in the build template?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild, installshield

**IDE:**

Visual Studio Premium 2012

Recently added **installshield project** for my solution in order to generate `setup.exe`. Manually when I build, everything seems to be working and `setup.exe` generated under bin.

**Problem :** 
When I trigger the build using TFS 2012 build, **`setup.exe` is not generated** under the drop folder and in log files I see that installshield project was not being built with MSbuild.

**Log Error:**
`.isproj is not supported by MSBuild and cannot be built`

On further analysis and research I found that MS build does not support certain project types. Also found an alternative [here](http://donovanbrown.com/post/I-need-to-build-a-project-that-is-not-supported-by-MSBuild.aspx) to build installshield project using devenv instead of MSbuild by modifying the workflow using build templates.

Even after following above solution I still encounter the same issue, `setup.exe` not generated and see the same issue in the log files.

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Have you configured the InstallShield project to be built by a 32-bit build context? InstallShield's build code is native 32-bit, but has supported MSBuild (and by extension TFS) for years.

Answer (score 0):

is the configuration and platform that you are specifying in the call to Devenv, set to build the install project? Have a look at the solution build config for the settings you are passing and ensure that the install project is ticked (set to build) for that configuration and platform